# welcome page does not display full address in browser

Tags: jsp, web.xml

My index.jsp is located at MyApp/web/views.

In my web.xml I have set

> ```
> <welcome-file-list>
>     <welcome-file>web/views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
> </welcome-file-list>
> ```

The page renders fine, but in the browser address bar it shows : localhost:8080/MyApp

I want it to show full address like localhost:8080/MyApp/web/views/index.jsp.
Any idea how to make this display ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the address bar to change, you must tell the browser to perform an additional request (redirect). Add a HTML page `MyApp/index.html` containing:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=web/views/index.jsp" />
    </head>
</html>
```

Using this, you will not need your `<welcome-file-list>` entry.